# How to highlight the max of each column in a contingency table?

Tags: r, printing, highlight, highlighting, contingency

I am trying to highlight the maximum value of each column in a contingency table in R.

**What I tried so far**

```
tbl <- as.matrix(table(c(iris[5], data.frame(Petal.Width = cut(iris$Petal.Width, 3)))))
pos <- cbind(apply(tbl, 2, which.max), 1:dim(tbl)[2])
tbl <- addmargins(tbl)

# First attempt
tbl2 <- tbl
tbl2[pos] <- -tbl2[pos]
tbl2
##             Petal.Width
## Species      (0.0976,0.9] (0.9,1.7] (1.7,2.5] Sum
##   setosa              -50         0         0  50
##   versicolor            0       -49         1  50
##   virginica             0         5       -45  50
##   Sum                  50        54        46 150

# Second attempt
tbl2 <- tbl
tbl[pos] <- paste("*", tbl[pos])
print(tbl, justify = "right")
##             Petal.Width
## Species      (0.0976,0.9] (0.9,1.7] (1.7,2.5] Sum 
##   setosa     * 50            0         0        50
##   versicolor    0         * 49         1        50
##   virginica     0            5      * 45        50
##   Sum          50           54        46       150
```

The first attempt would work if I could find a possibility to change the `"-"` to `"* "` but keep the numeric data type.

The second attempt would work if I could find a possibility to right align the values (which are now character strings) with the column names.

**My question**
Can you give me a solution to make at least one of these attempts work - or a completely different solution with which I can highlight the maximum value of each column in a contingency table?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is relatively unexpected due to some inconsistencies between different print methods in R:

```
tbl2 <- tbl
tbl[pos] <- paste("*", tbl[pos])
print(tbl, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE)
##             Petal.Width
## Species      (0.0976,0.7] (0.7,1.3] (1.3,1.9] (1.9,2.5] Sum
##   setosa             * 50         0         0         0  50
##   versicolor            0      * 28      * 22         0  50
##   virginica             0         0        21      * 29  50
##   Sum                  50        28        43        29 150
```

The documentation on `print.matrix` says:

> `print.matrix` and `print.default` both print matrices, and each has at
>   least an optional argument that the other lacks. Also, both directly
>   dispatch into `.Internal` code directly instead of relying on each
>   other. This mainly stems from historic compatibility and similar
>   reasons should be changed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the package 'formattable'.

```
install.packages("formattable")
library(formattable)

tbl_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
tbl_df_sub <- tbl_df[1:3,]

t <- formattable(tbl_df_sub, list(
  '(0.0976,0.9]'=color_tile("white", "green"),
  '(0.9,1.7]'=color_tile("white", "green"),
  '(1.7,2.5]'=color_tile("white", "green")
))
```

Result:

[image]

Downside is that it's only exportable as an image or html widget, not an actual table (although the table remains usable as such inside R).

This might not be what you are looking for, but I don't know what your goal is. If you simple want to highlight the table in the R console and still use the table values themselves, my solution isn't very good. Couldn't you simply use your first solution for the visual but keep a copy of the original table for any other stuff you want to do with it?